# I need show PDF into app android using appcelerator

Tags: pdf, webview, titanium, appcelerator

I'm development a app using appcelerator. I need display a url PDF inside this app but android webview dont show pdf.
I try for this pdf into google https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://xxx.pdf&embedded=true
But is instable, opening my webview android in white screen.

Somebody have a solution for open pdf into app android using appcelerator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Webview doesn't automatically load PDF files. You have to either use pdf.js and render it or use this module: https://github.com/SquirrelMobile/pdfview that will create a custom View to display PDF files